# Blackarch on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux

I am using blackarch linux and recently by mistake I deleted the live iso and soon I will be buying a new laptop on which I have to install blackarch for my personal use, so I am not having enough time to download the full live iso again. I am confused whether to install blackarch from netinstall iso or install arch linux and then install blackarch on it.
If I install blaclarch on arch linux, will I get a properly arranged menu of blackarch tools so that it is easy for me to navigate through tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you won't get the blackarch menu if you install it on top of arch linux. You will have all the tools but they won't be arranged.